# How to read bits of a file and write them elsewhere to regenerate the file in C

Tags: c, bit

Take this file: `myfile.txt` for instance.

How do I read the bits (1s and 0s) of this file and write them somewhere else in C to get the exact `myfile.txt`

Simply put I want to know how to regenerate files by reading and  rewriting their 1s and 0s in C.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a replacement for reading the mountain of existing material already available such as C books and tutorials. Basic I/O like this will be covered. In short you just need to open the source file, open the target file, and repeatedly read a block from source and write the block to target.

Comment: Are you asking how to copy a file? Call `read` and `write` in a loop!

Comment: Yes. Not mere copying. I want the 1s and 0s

Comment: There's no 1 s and 0 s. The smallest memory unit C can work with is a byte.

Comment: @dickson Not sure what you mean. What else would you be copying if not the underlying 1s and 0s that represent all digital systems. Please be clearer.

Comment: I want to read bits of a file and write them elsewhere in C. @kaylum

Comment: You are literally describing copying a file if you mean elsewhere on disk, or reading a file if you mean elsewhere in memory. Except for the bits part. Again, it's all bytes.

Comment: Yes @ikegami. But I want to 'play' with it's 1s and 0s

Comment: There's no 1 s and 0 s. It's all bytes. To play with those, you need to read the file. Just call `read` in a loop.

Comment: Repeat, what else would you be copying if not the bits? If you want to "play" with the bits then read them into a buffer, "play" with the values and then write them back out to a file. This is all very basic stuff that you can learn from thousands of books and tutorials.

Comment: Alright @kaylum.

Comment: @ikegami keeps saying there's no 1s and 0s.

Comment: @ikegami is right (ish). C does not have a built-in data type for ones and zeros (binary data). That said, some other data types (for example, an int), you can mess with the 1s and 0s using bitwise operations, if that is what you are referring to.

Comment: That's because you say "read arbitrary bits". There is no way to read/write anything smaller than one byte. For example, if you want the first bit of every byte you will still need to read each byte and then extract the bit once it is in memory. The problem is that your description is not clear for people to understand fully what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: @cocomac, You can also mess with the 2s, 3s and 4s... Numbers have those just as much as 0s and 1s.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking how to read an entire file into memory. This is done by calling `read` in a loop.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNK_SIZE ...

// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and errno set on error.
int read_file( int fd, char **buf_ptr, size_t *buf_size_ptr )
   *buf_ptr      = NULL;
   *buf_size_ptr = 0;

   char *buf = malloc( CHUNK_SIZE );
   if ( !buf )
      goto ERROR1;

   size_t total_bytes_read = 0;
   while ( 1 ) {
      ssize_t bytes_read = read( fd, buf + total_bytes_read, CHUNK_SIZE );
      if ( bytes_read == -1 )
         goto ERROR2;

      if ( bytes_read == 0 )
         break;

      total_bytes_read += bytes_read;

      char *tmp = realloc( buf, total_bytes_read + CHUNK_SIZE );
      if ( !tmp )
         goto ERROR2;

      buf = tmp;
   }

   {
      char *tmp = realloc( buf, total_bytes_read );
      if ( tmp ) {
         buf = tmp;
   }

   *buf_ptr      = buf;
   *buf_size_ptr = total_bytes_read ;
   return 0;

ERROR2:
   free( buf );
ERROR1:
   return -1;
}


int main( void ) {
   int fd = ...;

   char *buf;
   size_t buf_size;
   if ( read_file( ..., &buf, &buf_size ) == -1 ) {
      perror( NULL );
      exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
   }

   // Do something with buf...

   free( buf );

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Regenerating the file is simply writing the buffer to disk.

```c
// Returns 0 on success.
// Returns -1 and errno set on error.
int write_file( int fd, const char *buf, size_t buf_size ) {
   while ( buf_size > 0 )  {
      ssize_t bytes_written = write( fd, buf, buf_size );
      if ( bytes_written == -1 )
         return -1

      buf      += byte_written;
      buf_size -= byte_written;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All others have clarified that in C (and in any other programming language which is not hardware oriented) you need to cope with bytes as a minimum unit.

If you want to "play with bits", you can read bytes and then extract the single bits from them:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int readbit(FILE *f)
{
    static int buffer;
    static int n = 0;
    
    if (n == 0) {
        buffer = fgetc(f);
        if (buffer == EOF) {
            return EOF;
        }
        n = 8;
    }
    return (buffer >> --n) & 1;
}

int main(void) 
{
    for (int i = 0, bit; (bit = readbit(stdin)) != EOF; ++i) {
        printf("%d%c", bit, ((i + 1) % 8 == 0)*' ');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here you see a simple function that "reads bits" from a file. How? It reads and buffers a single byte, then it returns a bit of that byte.

The main function uses it to read `stdin` and send it in textual binary representation on standard output. If you try it with " a0" it sends to `stdout` "00100000 01100001 00110000 ", i.e. the binary representation of those three bytes (the numerical code for space is 32, for a is 97, for 0 is 48).

Try it online on [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/TiMeqF).

*DISCLAIMER: I'm not suggesting that this is a production ready function, nor that using static variables in functions is a good idea. But it makes everything simpler here. Don't multithread this.*